# Logout error in backend auth- not able to match access token

Tags: typescript, redis, access-token, mern

I am working on an LMS based software where currently I am working on the authentication part and for that I am using Typescript, Redis and MongoDB. I have created four routes as of now: Register, Activate-user, login and logout. Using access token and refresh token, I am able to generate access_token until login route but when i am logging out, it says please login to access all the resources which is an error I created for authentication if `access_token` doesn't matches with current token. With authentication I am successfully able to logout but with authentication which I have created, I am getting the created error. Can anyone help me find out why is that?
This is the image while I am accessing logout route:

[image: error]

This is my auth.ts which I am using as a middleware for authenticating:

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import { catchAsyncError } from "./catchAsyncError";
import ErrorHandler from "../utils/ErrorHandler";
import jwt, { JwtPayload } from "jsonwebtoken";
import { redis } from "../utils/redis";
export const isAuthenticated  = catchAsyncError(async(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) =>{
    const access_token = req.cookies.access_token as string;
    if(!access_token){
        return next(new ErrorHandler("Please login to access all the  resources.",  400));
    }
    
    const decoded = jwt.verify(access_token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN as string) as JwtPayload;
    if(!decoded){
        return next(new ErrorHandler("access token is not valid", 400));
    }
    const user = await redis.get(decoded.id);
    if(!user){
        return next(new ErrorHandler("user not found", 400));
    }
    req.user = JSON.parse(user);
    next();
});
```

This is my logout controller which i have created.
[image: logout controller]
// lOGOUT USER

```
export const logoutUser= catchAsyncError(
  async (req:Request, res:Response, next:NextFunction) =>{
try {
  res.cookie("access_token", "", {maxAge:1});
  res.cookie("refresh_token", "", {maxAge:1});
// delete data from redis database
  const userId = req.user?._id || "";
  // console.log(req.user);    
  redis.del(userId);
  res.status(200).json({
    suceess:true,
    message:"Logged out successfully",
  });

} catch (error:any) {
  return next(new ErrorHandler(error.message, 400));
}
  }
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not in the code!
When you login in the header u will receive the access_token and refresh_token like this:
[Response Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxW2G.png)

during logout u need to attach this in your header of the /logout request.
Like this:
[Request Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwLgW.png)